# or() operator with variable number of inputs

Tags: matlab, logical-or

Is there built-in a way to perform the array-wide logical `or` for a variable number of inputs?

Often Matlab functions seem designed with variable number of inputs as the default way to take in inputs. For example, in `size(A,dim1,dim2,…,dimN)`. `dim1,dim2,…,dimN` is a comma-separated list of unspecified length and is compatible with the `arr{:}` syntax where `arr` is a cell array which in term accepts variable length.

Here, the syntax `or(A,B)` where `A`, `B` are logical arrays do not accept more than two inputs. The syntax `A | B | C...` does accommodate multiple inputs but the syntax itself requires a known number of inputs beforehand.

Comment: How are you getting the variable number of inputs? An array with a special dimension? A cell array? Something else?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Something else. Each input is a function of an object and fieldname. The cell array of fieldnames is the variable part.

Comment: What is your current approach? I don't have anything better than a for loop.

Comment: I agree with Mad Physicist. Just use a for loop. That's simple enough. You're not going to make it shorter or faster than that.

Comment: Sorry, folks, I got mixed-up. The situation was what prompted me to ask the question. But I am more asking for a future reference: often matlab functions accept variable number of inputs that are compatible with the syntax `arr{:}` where `arr` is a cell array. I am wondering if there is something similar to that. For my original situation, I had to split it into cases and ensure everything is explicit; otherwise there is a big performance hit every step along the way and the difference in the `or` part is barely visible.

Comment: `Or = @(varargin) any([varargin{:}]);`

Comment: @rahnema1: iirc, `any` is `or` function applied across a particular dimension right? So `@(varargin)any([varargin{:}])` requires inputs to be 1D?

Comment: `[varargin{:}]` creates a vector if all elements of varargin are scalar or vector.

Comment: Extending @rahnema1’s suggestion: `cat(n,varargin{:})`, then apply `any` along dimension `n`. Adjust `n` to ensure it’s not an existing dimension in the input. But this might be slower than a loop, as you’re allocating a larger array and copying the data into it. For large arrays this could be prohibitive, for small arrays the whole thing is insignificant either way, so why not just loop?

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep these in mind